# perl client-to-server file sending and file retrieval

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm a newbie in stackoverflow and perl IO::Socket sockets programming and I have a problem with my project. I have a TCP client and server script where the client can send file to the server. The server side creates a directory where it stores the received received files.

Is it possible for me to view and retrieve/download the files that I have sent to the server?
My professor told me that if i could add these functions he would reconsider my project.

help would be greatly appreciated. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach will be to send a "string" command to the server that will trigger the server to scan the download directory for all file by using the code below

The names of the files can then be sent by the server app back through the client socket

Subsequently another string command for download can be sent to the server indicating the file path of the file your're interested in and you'll use the same process you used to send the file to the server in the first place to send it back to the client.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance I cant seem to catch up so i have to ask another question. Would the server be the one to send the file back to the client or would the client be able to retrieve the file by itself? :(

Comment: the server will have to send it back...kind of like turning things around. You could implement it the same was the client sent the file  to the server in the first place